# How to add a custom action for the same route as standard one in a ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Suppose, we have a ViewSet class:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
   def create(self, request):
      pass

   def custom_action(self, request):
      pass
```

and we register `SomeViewSet` as follows:

```
some_router = DefaultRouter()
some_router.register(r'some-route', SomeViewSet, basename='some-name')
```

So, now we have the `SomeViewSet` with the standard action `create`, which will be accessible with the route `some-route/` using `POST` HTTP method.

The question is how to configure the `custom_action` action to be accessible by the same route as a standard `create` action (`some-route/`) with the `PUT` HTTP method.

Comment: If it's `PUT`, is it not an option to just implement what `custom_action` is doing in `update()`?

Comment: @BrianDestura yes, but `update` is a `detail` action, so it will be required to pass a parameter to access a view. The route will be something like that `some-route/<pk>` instead of `some-route/` path.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
   def create(self, request):
      pass

   @action(detail=True, methods=["PUT"], url_name="custom_action")
   def custom_action(self, request):
      pass
```